# how to show pagination in wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i am working on wp_query for wordpress its works fine for me. Pagination is working on template pages but when i create a shortcode and try to display the pagination it is not working but the same code is working on template files
here is my query

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('cat=4&showposts=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
```

content display code

```
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

and finaly the pagination

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="twf_pagination">
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
</div>
```

anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong? and how can i fix it? thanx

Comment: where is your $args?

Comment: by the way this code is working fine in my template files .... problem is with the shortcode.

Answer (score -1):

You are completely breaking your main query here. You have the following issues here:

- Don't use the variable `$wp_query`. This is the global variable used and set by the main query. Rather use a variable like `$my_query`. Check out the codex, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to see how to construct a proper custom query
- Nowhere do I see that you are resetting the postdata. Use `wp_reset_postdata()` diretly after your pagination function
- Remember, the output from a shortcode should be returned, not echod. Either use a buffer to save your output and return that at the end or add your output to a variable and return that variable. Check out the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and learn how to properly construct a shortcode
- Check out the codex, [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) on how to properly use the use function with custom queries

Comment: This reply offers general advice that does not in any way pertain to the question asked.  As stated, his code works fine in template files; however, it does not work inside a shortcode.  The shortcode is the entire crux of the problem, and none of your suggestions resolve this.